# Many to many relationship with individual fields of a record

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I have a table called email_messages. I has columns `from`, `to`, `cc`, `bcc`. At the moment I have them stored as text fields, which contain serialized arrays of email addresses. But I want to extract the addresses into their own table, so I can reuse addresses and make it easier to search addresses with typeahead.

Obviously, I need a many to many. But if I do this:

```
class EmailMessage
  has_many :email_message_addresses
  has_many :addresses, through: :email_message_addresses
end

class Address
  has_many :email_message_addresses
  has_many :email_messages, through: :email_message_addresses
end
```

How would I be able to associate addresses for each individual `from`, `to`, `cc`, `bcc` field for a single record? The `from` field can contain 3 addresses, the `to` field can contain 5 addresses, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an attribute to email_message_addresses called `role`, which can take on the values `from`, `to`, etc.

You will probably want to add some methods so that you can do the following syntax

```
@message = EmailMessage.find(...)
@message.to_addresses  # -> array of addresses in the "to" field
@message.cc_addresses  # -> array of addresses in the "cc" field
#  etc.
```

Comment: So for each EmailMessage, there will be four EmailMessageAddress (from, to, cc, bcc), and for each EmailMessageAddress, there will be one or many addresses?

Comment: No.  If a given message has 1 person in the 'from field', 2 people in the 'to' field, 3 in 'cc', and '4' in bcc, then there will be 10 entries in EmailMessageAddress table (1 + 2 + 3 +4).